как убрать строку меню

я написал маленькое графическое приложение на библиотеке flet, и я хотел бы убрать данную строчку меню. возможно ли это в данной библиотеке?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

https://youtu.be/6sql8igT090?si=nAY8z5HDXZvOzcbF

спасибо, помогли
